# SQL Server: Joining in rows via. comma separated field

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to extract some data from a third party system which uses an SQL Server database. The DB structure looks something like this:

Order

```
OrderID   OrderNumber
   1         OX101 
   2         OX102
```

OrderItem

```
OrderItemID  OrderID   OptionCodes
     1          1      12,14,15
     2          1      14
     3          2      15
```

Option

```
OptionID   Description
    12      Batteries
    14      Gift wrap
    15      Case
[etc.]
```

What I want is one row per *order item* that includes a concatenated field with each option description. So something like this:

```
OrderItemID   OrderNumber   Options
    1            OX101      Batteries\nGift Wrap\nCase
    2            OX101      Gift Wrap
    3            OX102      Case
```

Of course this is complicated by the fact that the options are a comma separated string field instead of a proper lookup table. So I need to split this up by comma in order to join in the options table, and then concat the result back into one field.

At first I tried creating a function which splits out the option data by comma and returns this as a table. Although I was able to join the result of this function with the options table, I wasn't able to pass the OptionCodes column to the function in the join, as it only seemed to work with declared variables or hard-coded values.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If at all possible you want to add a related table to store option codes. A comma delimted list is a sign of incorrect database design unless it is used solely for display and will NEVER relate to another table or need data in the list to be searched by individual item. You need to fix bad design choices as soon as possible in a datbase. It only gets harder to fix them the longer they are let be.

Comment: @HLGEM - 100% agree, as you can see how difficult a simple thing like this is based on the solution I provided below.

Comment: @Yuck, I get a laugh out of your username everytime I see it. I picture you saying when you registered, "Oh Yuck, I have to come up with a username."

Comment: @HLGEM: Agreed, but as I said this database is part of a third party system so I have no control over the structure or poor design choices.

Comment: Sorry missed the third party system part. I have noticed that they very nearly always (there must be an exception somewhere) have bad database designs that don't follow even the most basic design rules like store only one piece of information in a field.

Comment: @HLGEM - Happy to be of service!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a splitting function (here's [an example](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)) to get individual values and keep them in a CTE. Then you can join the CTE to your table called "Option".

```
SELECT * INTO #Order
FROM (
  SELECT 1 OrderID, 'OX101' OrderNumber UNION SELECT 2, 'OX102'
) X;

SELECT * INTO #OrderItem
FROM (
  SELECT 1 OrderItemID, 1 OrderID, '12,14,15' OptionCodes
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 1, '14'
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 2, '15'
) X;

SELECT * INTO #Option
FROM (
  SELECT 12 OptionID, 'Batteries' Description
  UNION
  SELECT 14, 'Gift Wrap'
  UNION
  SELECT 15, 'Case'
) X;

WITH N AS (
  SELECT I.OrderID, I.OrderItemID, X.items OptionCode
  FROM #OrderItem I CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(OptionCodes, ',') X
)
SELECT Q.OrderItemID, Q.OrderNumber,
       CONVERT(NVarChar(1000), (
         SELECT T.Description + ','
         FROM N INNER JOIN #Option T ON N.OptionCode = T.OptionID
         WHERE N.OrderItemID = Q.OrderItemID
         FOR XML PATH(''))
       ) Options
FROM (
  SELECT N.OrderItemID, O.OrderNumber
  FROM #Order O INNER JOIN N ON O.OrderID = N.OrderID
  GROUP BY N.OrderItemID, O.OrderNumber) Q

DROP TABLE #Order;
DROP TABLE #OrderItem;
DROP TABLE #Option;
```

Comment: ...and I missed the second part of your question. There's a lot of examples on using `COALESCE` for string concatenation - even though just as many people advise against doing so as it's kind of hacky. IMHO, this feels like something you should be doing in a presentation layer and not as a SQL query.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I'm getting "OptionCodes" is not a recognised table hints option from the first bit, even if I run that SELECT on its own.

Comment: @Tim Fountain - I updated this with a self-contained testable solution.

Comment: Awesome - pasting your example as is into a fresh database works perfectly. But using the same code on the live database with the correct table names is still giving me the `"OptionCodes" is not a recognized table hints option` on the split. Could this relate to the 'database compatibilty mode' mentioned in the error? Or something in the live data?

Comment: When you're using a `WITH` statement any previous statements must be terminated with a `;`. You can try changing `WITH` to `;WITH`. Also did you add the function `dbo.Split()` to your database from the link I provided? It's not a part of standard T-SQL.

Comment: Changing the compatibility mode from 80 to 90 seems to have fixed it. Many thanks.